# ko.computed function does not update with "destroy"

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, tags

I have a text and a tag object that is loosely coupled via the textID-attribute.

To collect tags for a certain text I have a function "self.getTags" doing the matching. The tags are presented in my view with Ryan Niemeyers excellent ko.sortable library. This works fine.

However when I press the removeTag-button ("click: function(){$root.removeTag($data)};") on my tag the result of the "self.getTags"-function isn´t updated. Any hints highly appreciated

Here´s the code:

```
Text = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.textID = data.textID;
    self.projectID = data.projectID;
};

Tag = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.ID = data.ID;
    self.text = ko.observable(data.text);
    self.projectID = data.projectID;
    self.textID = data.textID;
    self._destroy = data._destroy || false;
};

viewModel = function(){

    //some code…

    self.selectedProject = ko.observable();
    self.Tags = ko.observableArray().syncWith("Tags", true);               
    self.projectTags = ko.computed(function () {
        var project = self.selectedProject();
        if (!project) {
            return [];
        }
        else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Tags(), function (t) {
                return t.projectID === project.projectID;
            })
        }
    });

    self.getTags = function (data) {
        return ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.projectTags(), function (t) {
                return t.textID === data.textID && !t._destroy;
            });
        });
    };

    // remove tag
    self.removeTag = function (tag) {
        self.Tags.destroy(tag);
        self.Tags.remove(tag); // I´ve tried to remove...
        self.Tags.push(tag);   // … and push the 'tag' back to trigger the computed.
    };
};
```

Then my view:

```
<div data-bind="with: $root.selectedText">
    <div class="tag-list" data-bind="sortable:{template:'tagsTmpl',data:$root.getTags($data)}"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="tagsTmpl"><div>
    <span class="tag-action remove" data-bind="click: function(){$root.removeTag($data)};">x</span>
    <span class="tag-text" data-bind="text: text"></span>  
</div></script>
```

Comment: You are using "getTags" as a source ... that is not computed observable so it wouldn't be updated when the underlying array changes.

Comment: Thanks, @Sam.C . Any suggestion to how I can fix this?

Comment: I stand corrected, with the latest knockout ... you can actually use functions as a source and knockout will automatically detect dependencies and make computed observable behind the scene. so I took a dumb down version of your code created this fiddle a POC http://fiddle.jshell.net/kshyyqa8/1/ the remove method seem to work for me.